# Another Checkbox gets Focus when I hover over the checkbox present in below Table Row

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am facing an issue inside a React App.

On clicking a button, a new Table row gets generated which contains a Checkbox as well. I have three such rows present on my Screen.

When I am trying to select the Checkbox present on Third or Second row, the Checkbox present on the First Row gets Focused and also gets checked.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, what does this issue mean and what can be the potential cause for this.

PS: I am New to Frontend!!

Comment: Where is your code?? Post the code that you have tried in the question.. If possible create example in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, I am just looking for some helping docs here or any such known behavior if faced by someone.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like issues was occurring because is was taking the same id for the checkbox field and thus it was only referring to the first one when I hover over the others, So do anyone knows any such behavior and have any potential solution for this? Please let me know. Thanks.